Errors Importing and Resolving Symbols in a Maven Project with Spring Boot
The issue involves a Maven project configured with Spring Boot where the import statements for Spring classes like org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders, @RestController, and @RequestMapping are not being recognized. This indicates a problem with dependencies or configuration in the project.
Here is my pom.xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.epitech.pictsmanager</groupId>
    <artifactId>pictsmanager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>pictsmanager</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

I tried to verify things in the pom.xml, but everything seems to be correct.
Please help me.

Did you tried Maven update?

can you try re-importing the project (or) add as a maven project? I have faced this issue in intelliJ sometimes and I have to either re-import the project or do a "Add as a maven project" if missed to do so earlier. Also in few cases, deleting the ".idea" folder and reimporting also works. Try and let us know.

Thank you very much for your reponses. I had to re-import the project as "maven project" and it worked.
Once again thank you very much
